# TcpClient Send Http Request and get response

Tags: c#, http

i just started with networking, learning how http worls and all that.

so my question is:

i have TcpClient connecting to an ip where website is located, but problem is that there is so many websites hosted on that server (goDaddy.com), I want to get contents of index.html,
of a website i want.

my code looks like that atm:

```
            connector = new TcpClient("******", 80);
            if(connector.Connected) Console.WriteLine("Connected\n");
```

so what kind of headers i need to send to apache so it gets the index.html for me,also would like to know the right way of sending it, without closing connection

Purpose for this:
-> I want to see headers that have been sent, and learn how to send my own headers.

big thanks in advance!

Comment: before trying to do HTTP requests, you should study HTTP, you can start at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP data exchange it is simplier to use HttpClient, not TcpClient.

Try to read MSDN for HttpClient.

Comment: ok:) thanks for your answers. i know how to dowload page. i want to see headers that are coming back from the server.

Comment: For this task you can use sample from this page: [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is what this site made for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use WebClient:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string content = client.DownloadString("http://website.com/index.html");
```

TcpClient is a very low level object; it is not recommended to start with that one.